# How to highlight an item of time-series in a ggplot2 plot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, time-series

I wish to highlight segments above or below a certain value in a time series by a unique colour or a shape.  In the example data I am decomposing a mortality time series into its components.  My goal is to highlight the segments when the mortality in the trend component falls below 35 (deep between 1997 and 2000) and when the residual component is above 100 (the spike). I have tried to use annotate, but that did not produce what I wanted.

```
#Load library and obtain data

library(gamair) 
library(tsModel)
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
data<-data(chicago)

## create variables, decompose TS
chicago$date<-seq(from=as.Date("1987-01-01"), to=as.Date("2000-12-31"),length=5114)
data<- chicago[,c("date","death")]
mort <- tsdecomp(data$death, c(1, 2, 15, 5114))

## Convert matrix to df, rename, melt
df<-as.data.frame(mort)
names(df)[1] <- "Trend"
names(df)[2] <- "Seasonal"
names(df)[3] <- "Residual"
df$date<-seq(as.Date("1987-01-01"), as.Date("2000-12-31"), "day")
meltdf <- melt(df,id="date")

##  Plot 

ggplot(meltdf,aes(x=date,y=value,colour=variable,group=variable)) + geom_line() +
theme_bw() +
ylab("") + xlab("") + 
facet_grid(variable ~ . , scales = "free") +
theme(legend.position = "none") 
annotate("rect", xmin=1995-01-01,xmax=1996-01-01,ymin= 10, ymax=300, alpha = .2,fill="blue")
```

[image]

Comment: You say " I have tried to use annotate, but that did not produce what I wanted."  How was the result different than what you wanted. You say you wish to highlight sections in a unique color or shape, but you have lines here and they are already different colors. Do you want to change color mid-line? What exactly is the desired output here?

Comment: @MrFlick My desire is to highlight the deep in the first plot and and the spike in the third. Annotate gave error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, this works but I must admit it's more work that I'd hoped.

```
get.box <- function(data) {
  rng <- range(data$date) + c(-50,50)
  z   <- meltdf[meltdf$date>=rng[1] & meltdf$date <=rng[2] & meltdf$variable==unique(data$variable),]
  data.frame(variable=unique(z$variable),
             xmin=min(z$date),xmax=max(z$date),ymin=min(z$value),ymax=max(z$value))
}
hilight.trend <- get.box(with(meltdf,meltdf[variable=="Trend" & value<35,]))
hilight.resid <- get.box(with(meltdf,meltdf[variable=="Residual" & value>100,]))
ggplot(meltdf,aes(colour=variable,group=variable)) + 
  geom_line(aes(x=date,y=value)) +
  theme_bw() +
  ylab("") + xlab("") + 
  facet_grid(variable ~ . , scales = "free") +
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  geom_rect(data=hilight.trend, alpha=0.2, fill="red",
            aes(xmax=xmax,xmin=xmin,ymax=ymax,ymin=ymin)) +
  geom_rect(data=hilight.resid, alpha=0.2, fill="blue", 
            aes(xmax=xmax,xmin=xmin,ymax=ymax,ymin=ymin))
```

[image]

You can't really use `annotate(...)` with facets, because you will get the same annotation on all the facets. So you're left with something like `geom_rect(...)`. The problem here is that `geom_rect(...)` draws a rectangle *for every row in the data*. So you need to create an auxiliary dataset with just one row for each `variable`, containing the x- and y- min and max.

Comment: @jihoward, thanks for the elegant solution. I assumed this could be possible to do for each facets.